# How to modify the key of {} to be a value of object Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm hoping to rearrage the key to be part of the object element.

```
{
123: [ {geoLong: 323, geoLat:4234}, {geoLong: 325, geoLat: 3422} ],
349: [ {geoLong: 768, geoLat:456}, 
       {geoLong: 7234, geoLat: 590}, 
       {geoLong: 7234, geoLat: 590} ],
958: [ {geoLong: 643, geoLat:290},  
       {geoLong: 567, geoLat: 378}],
...
}
```

To be something like the below result before I deflatten the object.

```
{
123: [ {geoLong: 323, geoLat:4234, id: 123}, 
       {geoLong: 325, geoLat: 3422, id: 123} ],
349: [ {geoLong: 768, geoLat:456, id: 349}, 
       {geoLong: 7234, geoLat: 590, id: 349}, 
       {geoLong: 7234, geoLat: 590, id: 349} ],
958: [ {geoLong: 643, geoLat:290, id: 958},  
       {geoLong: 567, geoLat: 378, id: 958}],
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do that.

```js
var data = { 123: [ {geoLong: 323, geoLat:4234}, {geoLong: 325, geoLat: 3422} ], 349: [ {geoLong: 768, geoLat:456}, {geoLong: 7234, geoLat: 590}, {geoLong: 7234, geoLat: 590} ], 958: [ {geoLong: 643, geoLat:290}, {geoLong: 567, geoLat: 378}] };

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  // Filter 'undefined' and 'null' values.
  data[key] = data[key].filter(item => item);

  data[key] = data[key].map(item => {
    item.id = key;
    return item;
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hi I get an error of  Cannot set property 'id' of undefined. Please advise.

Comment: @DuyDinh - Can you update your question with the data you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about updating my question with the data I'm using. @Nikihil

Comment: @DuyDinh - What is the variable `data` in your code?

Comment: Do you mean the type of the data? My object data has exact the same display to what I meantioned on the question.

Comment: @DuyDinh - If the data is same then you wouldn't get an error, you can see that my code is running without that error, right? Anyway, try my updated answer and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Nikhil I don't think he knows how to debug. If the data structure is the same as you and I expected, the above error cannot appear.

Comment: I'm still learning the language. Thank you for all your helps and patience.

Comment: You're welcome @DDD. We were also beginners when we started learning. Keep going!

Comment: @Nikhil I have one more question about the keys. After modifying the id, I want to get rid of the id key, to have all flat object list of vaules. Please advise.

Comment: @DDD - If `data` has your current result, then you can try `data = Object.values(data).flat(1);` Just add this line to the end of the code in my answer.

Comment: @Nikhil Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through object with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method.

```js
obj = {
123: [ {geoLong: 323, geoLat:4234}, {geoLong: 325, geoLat: 3422} ],
349: [ {geoLong: 768, geoLat:456}, 
       {geoLong: 7234, geoLat: 590}, 
       {geoLong: 7234, geoLat: 590} ],
958: [ {geoLong: 643, geoLat:290},  
       {geoLong: 567, geoLat: 378}],
}
```

```js
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, values]) => {
    values.forEach(item => item.id = (+key));
})
```

Result:

```js
{
  "123": [
    {
      "geoLong": 323,
      "geoLat": 4234,
      "id": 123
    },
    {
      "geoLong": 325,
      "geoLat": 3422,
      "id": 123
    }
  ],
  "349": [
    {
      "geoLong": 768,
      "geoLat": 456,
      "id": 349
    },
    {
      "geoLong": 7234,
      "geoLat": 590,
      "id": 349
    },
    {
      "geoLong": 7234,
      "geoLat": 590,
      "id": 349
    }
  ],
  "958": [
    {
      "geoLong": 643,
      "geoLat": 290,
      "id": 958
    },
    {
      "geoLong": 567,
      "geoLat": 378,
      "id": 958
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I get error on the second '.forEach': Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: please make sure your value of each keys is an array, otherwise you don't have forEach, map, ... if you data structure is not as same as the above snippet, please add some type check. the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks. But now I get this error : Cannot set property 'id' of undefined. Please advise

Comment: filter all `null, undefined` object in the array before assign `id`

Comment: Thank you so much. You're my life saver.

Comment: I have one more question. Now I want flatten the object element list. For example, after adding the 'id', I need to omit all the 'key' and flatten the object list. Please adivse.